# How to make my IP direct to my website instead of router?

Tags: server, apache2, ip, router, cisco

This has been a few hour struggle trying to figure this out (especially when i'm a total novice). I've found stuff on port directing, but can't really figure it out, watched a few YouTube videos and still lost. I'm using a Cisco router and when i use my IP it goes to my router settings instead of my website. I thought i had it figured out by using my ipv4 address (whatever that is), i can get to my site from my computer no problem with the URL now...but no one else can.

Comment: Short version: Add a port forward from port 80 (TCP only, if offered the option) to your internal IP address (192.168.xxx.xxx).

Answer (score 1):

Forward port `80` and `443` to the local server that is hosting your site. For more information on port forwarding please visit http://portforward.com/.

Explaination of ports

HTTP  - 80/TCP

HTTPS - 443/TCP

Comment: I got it working...locally, I set up a static IP for my computer and added my IP to the DHCP Reservation list. I did the port forwarding, but nothing it's allowing anyone to connect to my site.

Comment: Now i got it online. I went in to my router status and found "Internet IP". Typed that IP in to my phone (which is not connected to the router) and it worked.

Comment: Sounds great! Everyone's router is different, unless they modify them to use popular alternative firmwares like Tomato or DD-WRT.

Answer (score 0):

Got it, all i had to do was open a browser in nautilus and edit a configuration file in etc/apache2/sites-available/ to "phpbb" instead of "html"